# How can I find all the elements in javaScript array that start with certain letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

Is there any way to do this filtering out only items in an array that start with the letter a. ie

```
var fruit = 'apple, orange, apricot'.split(',');
  fruit = $.grep(fruit, function(item, index) {
  return item.indexOf('^a'); 
  });
alert(fruit);
```

Comment: Try this in jQuery: `var $beginswitha = $(":input[name^='a']")`. Then place that variable in your indexOf statement.

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

- You want to split by `', '`, not `','`
- `indexOf` doesn't take a regex, but a string, so your code searches for a literal `^`. Use `search` if you want to use regular expressions.
- `indexOf` (and `search`) do return the index where they find the sought-after term. You'll have to compare that to your expectation: `== 0`. Alternatively, you can use the regex `test` method which returns a boolean.

```
alert('apple, orange, apricot'.split(', ').filter(function(item, index) {
    return item.indexOf('a') == 0; 
}));
alert('apple, orange, apricot'.split(', ').filter(function(item, index) {
    return /^a/.test(item); 
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `trim` the spaces from the `item` before checking.

Regex to check if start with: `^a`

```
var fruit = 'apple, orange, apricot'.split(',');
fruit = $.grep(fruit, function (item, index) {
    return item.trim().match(/^a/);
});
alert(fruit);
```

Other solution:

```
var fruits = [];
$.each(fruit, function (i, v) {
    if (v.match(/^a/)) {
        fruits.push(v);
    }
});
alert(fruits);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks alot. Im very new to javascript so much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charAt` like so :

```
var fruit = 'apple, orange, apricot'.split(', ');
  fruit = $.grep(fruit, function(item, index) {
  return item.charAt(0) === 'a';
});
alert(fruit);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Cheers for that